# Custom Chapter Heading

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, chapters

I am writing a book using the `book` document class. I have used a template I found online to make my chapter headings look like this:

[image: My book]

I would prefer to add an image to my chapter heading and achieve an effect similar to this:

[image: Operating System Concepts - Introduction]

Is there a particular package that allows me to modify the chapter heading in such a way? I have no idea how to go about it, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `Titlesec` allows you to do about what you want, but the problem is LaTeX can't simply produce such an image. Is it for a comic book?

Comment: @Bernard Can I import my own image using Titlesec?

Comment: Via `\includegraphics`, yes (if it's in one of the formats known to `pdflatex`).

Comment: @Bernard Could you give me an example of how the syntax would look? Especially to overlay the chapter number over the image. I've been reading through the documentation but I haven't managed to grasp it.

Comment: I tagged this `tikz-pgf`. Maybe it attracts some users.

Comment: @Johannes_B - thanks, I'd still be interested in a solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give you something to start with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{fix-cm}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

% formats: \chapter
\newcommand\ctformatchapter[1]{%
    \parbox[b][6cm][b]{\dimexpr.5\textwidth\relax}{%
        \raggedright%
        \textcolor{cyan!50!blue}{\textsf{#1}}%
    }%
}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\bfseries\selectfont}%
{%
    \raggedleft{%
        \begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{ctan-lion}
            \put (30,42) {\rotatebox{-20}{\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont\textsf{\Roman{chapter}}}}
            \put (20,50) {\textcolor{cyan!50!blue}{\textsf{Chapter}}}
        \end{overpic}               
    }%
}%
{-6.5cm}%
{\ctformatchapter}%
[\phantomsection]   

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]