Thesis chapter design
Do you know how I can format the chapter titles in LaTeX to appear like they do in this picture?

see if something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94732/36296 might give you a starting point.

or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298046/custom-chapter-heading

In general, package titlesec is your friend for this task. Even its manual has an example somewhat close to what you are asking.

@nplatis that depends on the document class the OP is using. There are a few classes titlesec should not be used with.

Welcome to TeX.SE.

@daleif please provide some details; it could also help the OP if they use some other class than book since both previous comments/suggestions refer to the book class.

here's the solution:
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{0.647, 0.129, 0.149}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\chapterbox}
\newcommand{\customchapter}[1]{
    \vspace*{0cm} 
    \hbox{%
        \vbox{%
            \hbox to \textwidth{%
                \hspace*{\fill} 
                \tikz[baseline=(n.base)]{
                    \node[draw=nicered, fill=nicered, text=white, circle, inner sep=10pt] (n) {\bfseries\Huge\thechapter};
                }
                \hspace{0.8em}%
                \normalfont\Huge\textsc{Chapter}%
            }
            \vspace{1em}
            \hbox to \textwidth{\hspace*{\fill}\color{nicered}\rule{16cm}{0.9pt}} 
        }
    }
    \vspace{0cm}
    {\raggedright\Huge\bfseries\textsc{#1}\par}     \vspace{1cm}
}


\renewcommand\chapter{%
    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain} % Appliquer le style de page standard
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \customchapter{#1} 
}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }}
\makeatother

